# Run 2 Svelte project simuletanelously

Tags: svelte, livereload

I tried running two svelte projects using `npm run dev`, however the second one gives the error `Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::35729`.

I have looked online for a solution with no avail.

Where can i modify this configuration to select another port.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Judging by the [code of rollup-plugin-livereload](https://github.com/thgh/rollup-plugin-livereload/blob/master/src/index.js), you can assign a port.

In your `rollup.config.js` file,
Change:
`!production && livereload('public'),`
to
`!production && livereload({watch: 'public', port: 35730}),`

It seems [rollup-plugin-livereload](https://github.com/thgh/rollup-plugin-livereload/blob/master/src/index.js) automatically assigns to port 35729 and prints the error if it is already in use.

Though, it uses [port-authority](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/port-authority) which I thought would automagically find an open port, but anyway, the above change to your rollup.config.js should hopefully still solve your problem.

I have not actually tested this, but I would expect it to work.

Comment: Thank you this solved my issue, as for port-authority i used to run 2 projects simultaneously on my windows machine and i did not encounter any errors. however now i installed linux and encountered this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I removed my previous answer, since I didn't understand the problem was with the livereload port, not the web server port.

I just tested in my system with a new fresh svelte project, and pre-opened a webserver in the port `35729`, and svelte automatically changed its livereload port to `35730`

Comment: yes, it is the first time i encountered this issue, before i used to run 2 projects simultaneously without any issue.